# Squid proxy for localhost to improve surfing experience

Tags: networking, proxy, squid

I think of using Squid as a proxy for my localhost to improve my surfing experience. Now I have done some research on this and I'm not sure why there is not much content about this on Google:

1. Can Squid as a proxy for localhost be a security issue?
2. Is it worth to run squid locally to improve my surfing experience? I don't have a slow internet connection but I think of it being useful for sites I frequently visit and to reduce requests to websites and content to be transferred.
3. If squid is an security issue (for example if you use it for privacy reasons with a VPN, I2P/TOR, or similar services), how to make it safer? For example how to be sure I do not cache sensitive bank information while I do cache Wikipedia or other insensitive information without maintaining white-/blacklists.

It feels like the literature on this is rare because this idea results in nasty stuff like new security issues or it won't matter at all regarding performance and thus is unnecessary to do.

Comment: What's your theory of how Squid could speed up your browsing? Do you think your browser isn't caching enough data for long enough, so you want to use Squid to cache more for longer?

Comment: Yes, I think Squid could cache longer and better as I do use privacy mode in Firefox. Maybe it is also able to cache the requests itself and the routing or something so it doesn't only cache content but also requests and improves routing. In past I had sometimes better ping with VPN and I noticed in past faster surfing speed with squid on a remote server near to my home location (not localhost). In both cases I'm not sure it's just luck or if that's reproducible.